# Installing boost boost:x64-windows-static uses openssl dynamic libs instead of static ones

Tags: c++, static-linking, vcpkg

I want to create a fully statically linked app, no Visual C runtime and no third party dlls if static libs are available for those.
Previously I were building the thirdparty libs myself, but wanted to one package manager, and now testing VCPKG.
Unfortunately it is being very difficult from the start, it seems VCPKG is not a good choice so far.

I started installing VCPKG by doing this

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
.\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
.\vcpkg\vcpkg install boost:x64-windows-static
```

But I found that when compiling my exe with boost I ended up creating an executable that relies on openssl dynamic libs (libcrypto and libssl), as you can see here

```
dumpbin /DEPENDENTS test_util.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.30.30705.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file test_util.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Image has the following dependencies:

    KERNEL32.dll
    WS2_32.dll
    CRYPT32.dll
    libcrypto-3-x64.dll
    libssl-3-x64.dll
```

vcpkg list shows a lot of non static libs being installed as a consequence of installing boost, openssl:x64-windows among them, I expected to see openssl:x64-windows-static instead among with others.

If I try installing openssl:x64-windows-static lib before installing boost nothing changes

I am really frustrated on VCPKG, and plan to switch to https://conan.io/ package manager instead, but would like to ask first.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When running `cmake build`, add the `-v` flag to see the compile and link output. I ran into this problem a while back and IIRC I had to change the compiler flag `/MD`, to `/MT`. Also, verify that the link library paths include the openssl static libraries.